# Unattended SQL installation on non-English PC?

Tags: sql-server, installation, wix

We are attempting to distribute an application that uses Wix to perform an unattended SQL 2019 Express install.  The install command is as follows:

```
/ACTION=Install 
/INSTANCENAME=$(var.InstanceName) 
/FEATURES=SQL 
/SECURITYMODE=SQL [SqlVariable] 
/TCPENABLED=1 
/SQLSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE&quot; 
/SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic 
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators 
/ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=FALSE 
/Q 
/IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms
```

This works fine on an English PC however on non-English environments we run into problems because "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" and "BUILTIN\Administrators" are named in their native languages.  I tried to use

```
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\S-1-5-32-544
```

or just

```
/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=S-1-5-32-544
```

however no luck.  Any ideas on how to extract the proper names for any language or use the SID in the command?

Comment: Seems I can use the WixUtilExtension to extract [WIX_ACCOUNT_ADMINISTRATORS] and [WIX_ACCOUNT_NETWORKSERVICE], however I can't figure out how to capture them as variables and substitute them into my InstallCommand string.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to PowerShell, you could look it up:

```
$administrators = (get-localgroup -SID S-1-5-32-544).Name
```